# cannot borrow `...` as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust

Есть такой код:

```
fn count_sort<'a, D, T: 'a>(data: &'a mut D, min: T, max: T)
    where   &'a mut D: IntoIterator<Item = &'a mut T>,
            T: Sort + Clone + AddAssign,
            usize: From<T> {
    let mut count = vec![0usize; usize::from(max) - usize::from(min) + 1usize];

    for e in data.into_iter() {
        count[usize::from(e.clone())] += 1usize;
    }

    let mut i = T::ZERO;
    let mut iter = data.into_iter();
    for e in count.iter() {
        for _ in 0usize..*e {
            *iter.next().unwrap() = i.clone();
        }

        i += T::ONE;
    }
}
```

И выдает он такую ошибку:

> `error[E0499]: cannot borrow`*data`as mutable more than once at a time
>     --> src\main.rs:21:20
>      |
>   16 |     for e in data.into_iter() {
>      |              ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
>   ...
>   21 |     let mut iter = data.into_iter();
>      |                    ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
>   ...
>   29 | }
>      | - first borrow ends here`

Я понимаю в чем заключается ошибка, у ссылок на **16** и **21** строчках одинаковый `lifetime`, ведь я это указал в блоке `where`, но не понимаю, как это исправить, чтобы все работало. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Полный код, если надо:

```
use std::ops::AddAssign;



trait Sort {
    const ZERO: Self;
    const ONE: Self;
}

fn count_sort<'a, D, T: 'a>(data: &'a mut D, min: T, max: T)
    where   &'a mut D: IntoIterator<Item = &'a mut T>,
            T: Sort + Clone + AddAssign,
            usize: From<T> {
    let mut count = vec![0usize; usize::from(max) - usize::from(min) + 1usize];

    for e in data.into_iter() {
        count[usize::from(e.clone())] += 1usize;
    }

    let mut i = T::ZERO;
    let mut iter = data.into_iter();
    for e in count.iter() {
        for _ in 0usize..*e {
            *iter.next().unwrap() = i.clone();
        }

        i += T::ONE;
    }
}


impl Sort for u8 {
    const ZERO: u8 = 0;
    const ONE: u8 = 1;
}


fn main() {
    let mut data = [3u8, 0, 2, 1];

    println!("data = {:?}", data);
    count_sort(&mut data, 0, 3);
    println!("data = {:?}", data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае нужно использовать [Higher-Rank Trait Bounds](https://github.com/ruRust/rustonomicon/blob/master/src/hrtb.md):

```
fn count_sort<D, T>(data: &mut D, min: T, max: T)
    where   for <'x> &'x mut D: IntoIterator<Item = &'x mut T>,
            T: Sort + Clone + AddAssign,
            usize: From<T>
```

Вот еще [отличный ответ на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35595491/5138648), где объясняется что это за магия.

P.S. У вас еще перепутаны местами `min` и `max` при создании вектора, rust выкидывает ошибку переполнения.